# ReaderWriterLockSlim implements single writer, or requires single writer?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I think I am having a brain fart.

This sould be a very simple question:  does ReaderWriterLockSlim IMPLEMENT the single writer concept, or does it REQUIRE a single writer thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ensures that protected resource can have either one writer thread or multiple reader threads. So it implements the single writer concept.

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't believe I had to ask that question.